# Using for-each loop to make iteration for specific obj

Tags: javascript, json

I have oracle table like this and using ajax call to retrieve the table data in array in javascript.

```
starttime      endtime
 10:00 am        02:00 pm
 05:00 am        05:00 pm
 03:00 am        02:00 pm
 08:00 am        10:00 pm
 09:00 am        07:00 pm
 06:00 am        04:00 pm
```

in returning data I want to loop  like this

```
obj[0].starttime,
obj[1].endtime,
obj[2].starttime,
obj[3].endtime,
obj[4].starttime,
obj[5].endtime
```

Since there will be many record in the same table , I need to use an intelligent way to resolve this issue smoothly.

Any idea ?

Comment: `for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) ...`

Comment: do you mean `obj[0].starttime, obj[0].endtime`?

Comment: it will be kind of Cartesian retrieving. obj[1].endtime

Comment: single for loop is not working since I am going to use startime and endtime as I displayed on the second part .

Comment: what exactly is the question? how to make the for-each or the obj?

Comment: What exactly is "this issue" you want to resolve, i.e. why you need a loop? Do you want to use/modify the values in that array in a loop? Maybe populate another array or object with values? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var len = obj.length / 2;

for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {

    var start = obj[i*2].starttime;
    var end = obj[i*2+1].endtime;

    // do something with the times
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your issue is, but if you're just trying to loop the obj and use starttime and endtime of alternative objects, you can use:

```
for (var i in obj){
    if(i%2 ==0){
         alert(obj[i].starttime);
    }else{
         alert(obj[i].endtime);
    }
}
```

Please tell me if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

Javascript

```
var ajaxData = [{
        starttime: '10:00 am',
        endtime: '02:00 pm'
    }, {
        starttime: '05:00 am',
        endtime: '05:00 pm'
    }, {
        starttime: '03:00 am',
        endtime: '02:00 pm'
    }, {
        starttime: '08:00 am',
        endtime: '10:00 pm'
    }, {
        starttime: '09:00 am',
        endtime: '07:00 pm'
    }, {
        starttime: '06:00 am',
        endtime: '04:00 pm'
    }];

ajaxData.forEach(function (record, index) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        console.log('starttime: ', record.starttime);
    } else {
        console.log('endtime: ', record.endtime);
    }
})
```

Output

```
starttime:  10:00 am 
endtime:  05:00 pm 
starttime:  03:00 am 
endtime:  10:00 pm 
starttime:  09:00 am 
endtime:  04:00 pm
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/y6pM3/)